# How to change the height of the dropdown box from the ComboBox component in Vuetify 3?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

In vuetify 3, combobox component, I have hundreds of items in the dropdown. When I open the menu, the dropdown covers the whole screen from top to bottom and it hides the field where I can type in. I want to reduce the height of the dropdown. I figured some hacky css that fixes it

```
  div[target] > .v-list[role='listbox'] {
    max-height:300px;
  }
```

but I don't want to do this. Does anyone know some vuetify best practice way to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Solution is just add

```
:menu-props="{ maxHeight: 300 }"
```

to the `v-combobox` component.